# creating a data frame with two colums each preserving the class characters of each assembled vector

Tags: r

I have two vectors one is a character vector and another a numeric vector. I am trying to assemble both in a data frame while preservinf their class properties, however none of the methods below seem to work as wither all appear in quotes or the opposite. How could I create a data frame where the vector element properties are preserved.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
y <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")

cbind(x,y)
as.data.frame(x,y)
as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

EDIT - Desired Output

      x   y   
      1  "a"          
      2  "b"          
      3  "c"          
      4  "d"
      5  "e"          
      6  "f"         
      7  "g"          
      8  "h" 

Following several comments on it, please see that still does not appear.

sapply(data.frame(x,y, stringsAsFactors=FALSE), class)
           x           y 
       "numeric"   "character"

data.frame(x,y, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 4 d
5 5 e
6 6 f
7 7 g
8 8 h

x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
y
[2] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"
```

Comment: You can use `df1 <- data.frame(x,y, stringsAsFactors=FALSE); sapply(df1, class)`

Comment: don't use `as.data.frame`, use `data.frame`. This is very clear from reading the help file (ie- read the help file)

Comment: However the quotes on y do not appear on the column elements of the data frame, see edit

Comment: Looks like a formatting issue.  You can do almost the same operations with the vector columns iin the data.frame.  So, I am not sure why this `""` is a problem.  If you extract the `vector` i.e. `df1$y
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"`

Comment: The desired output looks like a `matrix`, just do `cbind(x,y)`, but in that case there will be only a single class ie. `character`.  It is not clear why you need it in this format.

Comment: I need it in this format to passed to a function which I use this as index

Comment: If you can provide more info about the end result, this might be easier and there would be other ways to solve rather than using a format that can't work.

Comment: How about creating a `list` i.e. `lst <- list(x,y)`  You can access the elements with `lst[[1]]` or `lst[[2]]`.

Comment: A matrix output with two class is not possible.  Why don't you read the documents ie. `?matrix` before asking this kind of questions?

Comment: Because the format is not about a matrix but a data frame.

Comment: But you showed the `Desired Output` as a `matrix`.  You may create a new class and change the print properties of 'Data.frame'.  I am not sure why that is needed.

Comment: Well I can not show it as a data frame that is why I am asking the question to have the output of the colums as in the desired output. If the desired output elements format of each colum is not clear, I do not know what to say

Comment: As I said earlier, you can create  custom class and new print properties for data.frame.  The default options doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your character vector is automatically turned into a vector of factors. 
 `data.frame` will allow a function input which doesn't turn character strings into factors:

```
df<-data.frame(x,y,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**Edit: In light of clarification in the question by OP**

Adds in the required quote marks using the escape character to print "y", instead of y

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
> y <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
> df<-data.frame(x,paste0("\"",y,"\""),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> names(df)<-c("x","y")
> print(df, row.names = FALSE)
 x   y
 1 "a"
 2 "b"
 3 "c"
 4 "d"
 5 "e"
 6 "f"
 7 "g"
 8 "h"
> sapply(df, class)
          x           y 
  "numeric" "character"
```

Comment: I have tried your solution and does not work How can you get a positive vote if the result does not work.

Comment: Any clarification on why it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes the character colum is not preserved as it appears as indicated in the EDIT of the question

Comment: So you don't want the row numbers?

Comment: It is fine, thanks thought in an easier solution to preserve the class of a column than paste which ofcourse will cause some issues when passed as an index to another function, but that is another issue.

Comment: In desired Output there are no row numbers

Comment: Yes, I edited it to not show the row numbers, as per the desired output from your example.

Comment: Never though so difficult to have two classes in each column of dataframe easly passed if needed to index to another function by the use of  - substr -